# Android RelativeLayout My Own MousePadView

Tags: android, android-layout

Please help me to fix the code below. 
I am making a mousepad view for my Android Remote Application.

```
public class MousePadView extends RelativeLayout {

    private float scale;

    // MOUSE BUTTONS LEFT CLICK, MIDDLE CLICK, RIGHT CLICK

    private LinearLayout layoutMouseButtonBody;
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsMouseButtonBody;

    private Button left;
    private Button middle;
    private Button right;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsButtons;

    // BUTTONS FOR MOUSEWHEEL (UP AND DOWN)

    private LinearLayout layoutWheelsBody;
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsWheelBody;
    private Button up;
    private Button down;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsWheelButton;

    public MousePadView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { // CONSTRUCTOR
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; // GET SCALE FOR CONVERTING DPI TO PIXELS

        // MOUSE BUTTON LAYOUT

        paramsButtons = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(DpiToPixels(0), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
        left = new Button(context);
        left.setText("L");
        left.setLayoutParams(paramsButtons);
        middle = new Button(context);
        middle.setText("M");
        middle.setLayoutParams(paramsButtons);
        right = new Button(context);
        right.setText("R");
        right.setLayoutParams(paramsButtons);

        paramsMouseButtonBody = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsMouseButtonBody.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM); // RELATIVE LAYOUT RULES
        paramsMouseButtonBody.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT); // RELATIVE LAYOUT RULES
        paramsMouseButtonBody.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT); // RELATIVE LAYOUT RULES
        layoutMouseButtonBody = new LinearLayout(context);
        layoutMouseButtonBody.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.bottom_bar);
//      layoutMouseButtonBody.setPadding(0, DpiToPixels(4), 0, 0);
        layoutMouseButtonBody.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layoutMouseButtonBody.setLayoutParams(paramsMouseButtonBody);
        layoutMouseButtonBody.addView(left);
        layoutMouseButtonBody.addView(middle);
        layoutMouseButtonBody.addView(right);

        // WHEELS

        paramsWheelButton = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        up = new Button(context);
        up.setText("U");
        up.setLayoutParams(paramsWheelButton);
        down = new Button(context);
        down.setText("D");
        down.setLayoutParams(paramsWheelButton);

        paramsWheelBody = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(DpiToPixels(32), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsWheelBody.addRule(LEFT_OF, layoutMouseButtonBody.getId());
        paramsWheelBody.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        layoutWheelsBody = new LinearLayout(context);
        layoutWheelsBody.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layoutWheelsBody.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.bottom_bar);
        layoutWheelsBody.setLayoutParams(paramsWheelBody);
        layoutWheelsBody.addView(up);
        layoutWheelsBody.addView(down);

        // PARENT
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        addView(layoutMouseButtonBody); // add mousebutton layout in parent (relativelayout)
        addView(layoutWheelsBody); // add mousewheel button layout in parent (relativelayout)
    }


    private int DpiToPixels(int dp) {
        return (int)(dp * scale + 0.5f); // converting DPI to Pixels
    }

}
```

[image: The output generated by Android SDK]
[image: This is the output that I want]

The image on the Left is the output generated by Android SDK and The right one is the output that I want.

Please Help me.

I don't want to inflate layout from XML.

Comment: You can still suggest code. :)

Comment: I've got LayoutInflaterException 

add this constructor

  public MousePadView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     this(context, attrs, 0);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }


 public MousePadView(Context context) {
   this(context, null, 0);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to achieve what you're looking for is by grouping both your wheel and button layout into another layout. After that, simply align the result to the bottom of the parent.

Add something like this:

```
LayoutParams paramsTotal = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramsTotal.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
LinearLayout layoutTotal = new LinearLayout(context);
layoutTotal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layoutTotal.setLayoutParams(paramsTotal);
layoutTotal.addView(layoutWheelsBody);
layoutTotal.addView(layoutMouseButtonBody);

// PARENT
setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
addView(layoutTotal); // add the combined layout
```

That should place the wheel buttons right above the mouse buttons (or vice versa: the mouse buttons directly below the wheel buttons) and the combination all the way at the bottom.

//Edit: alternatively, you could make the root layout a LinearLayout and add a dummy view with a weight of '1' at the top, which will push the other elements down to the bottom. I'd probably prefer the RelativeLayout option though.

Just out of curiousity: why not just inflate the layout? Personally I find that way more managable.

Comment: Thanks for your code. Nice Code.  :)

Why? I have a lot of XML layouts in my project such as layout for Activities, customized dialogs and customized item for listview :)

Another reason: Experience :)

Answer (score 0):

Your layout management is messed up. I suggest using this code:

```
        // MOUSE BUTTON LAYOUT

        paramsButtons = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(DpiToPixels(0), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
        left = new Button(context);
        left.setText("L");
        middle = new Button(context);
        middle.setText("M");
        right = new Button(context);
        right.setText("R");

        paramsMouseButtonBody = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsMouseButtonBody.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM); // RELATIVE LAYOUT RULES

        layoutMouseButtonBody = new LinearLayout(context);
        layoutMouseButtonBody.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.bottom_bar);
//      layoutMouseButtonBody.setPadding(0, DpiToPixels(4), 0, 0);
        layoutMouseButtonBody.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layoutMouseButtonBody.addView(left, paramsButtons );
        layoutMouseButtonBody.addView(middle, paramsButtons );
        layoutMouseButtonBody.addView(right, paramsButtons );

        // WHEELS

        paramsWheelButton = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        up = new Button(context);
        up.setText("U");
        down = new Button(context);
        down.setText("D");

        paramsWheelBody = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(DpiToPixels(32), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsWheelBody.addRule(ABOVE, layoutMouseButtonBody.getId());

        layoutWheelsBody = new LinearLayout(context);
        layoutWheelsBody.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layoutWheelsBody.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.bottom_bar);
        layoutWheelsBody.addView(up, paramsWheelButton);
        layoutWheelsBody.addView(down, paramsWheelButton);

        // PARENT
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        addView(layoutMouseButtonBody, paramsMouseButtonBody ); // add mousebutton layout in parent (relativelayout)
        addView(layoutWheelsBody, paramsWheelBody); // add mousewheel button layout in parent (relativelayout)
```

Comment: Does it work for you? If so please consider accepting the answer

Comment: @Anton: I think `paramsWheelBody.addRule(ABOVE, layoutMouseButtonBody.getId());` will result in the layout just sitting at the top of the screen. There's nothing telling the layout to position itself directly on top of the buttons at the bottom...

Comment: @Anton MH is right. I'm still waiting for suggestions or answers. :)